# how to get rid of this plugin's class_inheritable_attribute deprecation warning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, deprecated

I'm getting this warning for a plugin I'm using:

```
 DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from has_private_messages at /vendor/plugins/simple-private-messages/lib/has_private_messages_extensions.rb:17)
```

I've created an issue at https://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages, but there isn't much recent activity on it.

I'm not familiar with class_inheritable_attribute...  don't know how to patch this myself.  Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fork the plugin on GitHub and find the calls to `class_inheritable_attribute` and change them to `class_attribute`. Remove the old plugin from your `vendor/plugins` directory and add the new one. That would remove the deprecation warning.